# Placing holograms/gameobjects on world mesh with Hololens 2 using MRTK2-Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

slight noob question and I may have missed something in the MRTK2-Unity docs/samples etc but I'm just getting back into Unity with the Hololens 2 and I'm looking for a simple example of dropping holograms onto the world mesh, rather like the original Hololens 1 [MR 250 tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mixed-reality-250#chapter-2---interaction), using the old HoloToolKit: WorldAnchorManager and TapToPlace approach.

I'm sure this is quite a simple thing to achieve but can't seem to find an example now that the HoloToolKit "Manager Prefabs" approach has been replaced by the MRTK services etc.

I want to update some old HL1 projects to HL2 but the [Porting Guide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.3.0/Documentation/HTKToMRTKPortingGuide.html) is either a bit unclear, or more likely, designed to be interpreted by clever people who know what they are doing...

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the new approach with `Solvers` :
[MRLearning-Base-Ch3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch3)

Most of old HoloToolkit managers are now integrated into services but you will find all functions that you need.

The Porting Guide explain what changed, I don't really understand what is unclear in this guide ... Can you develop ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  I went though that tutorial but like all the others, it didn't seem to cover spawning on the world mesh or interacting with it in any way and also any local world anchor type creation that may or may not be necessary with the new services (eg when you're when NOT using Azure Spatial Anchors).
Full disclosure: I haven't used Unity for many years and I am not what anyone would call a coder...but if there is an example that covers the basic components/code of spawning on the world mesh then I can usually hack it to achieve what I need.  
cheers.

Comment: Download the MRTK Unity and you will find under Assets > MixedRealityToolkit.Examples > Demos > Solvers > Scenes a TaptoPlace example scene. This example should cover the spawning of an object in the world mesh surface with no remote anchors ! Good luck in your dev ;)

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for  that Alex.  Poking about in that now...  
Seems like a great start.  Just what I was looking for.  :-)
cheers!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as solution if it answer your question ;)

Comment: Oh.  Good point.  I can confirm that the TapToPlace example does indeed allow spawning to world mesh!  I've marked it, but don't have enough points or whatever for it to display. Thanks again for your help.